# .htaccess not working after page slug change

Tags: redirect, htaccess, slug

I used to have a page called /page-title

I then changed the page slug to /page-new-title

I was under the impression that WordPress automatically set up a 301 re-direct when changing a page slug, but this doesn't seem to be the case. As a result, I have added the following 301 re-direct via .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

# X-XSS-Protection
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
</IfModule>

# X-Frame-Options
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
</IfModule>

# Security Headers - X-Content-Type: nosniff
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
</IfModule>

Redirect 301 /page-title/ https://www.domain.com/page-new-title/
```

The re-direct worked initially, but then started showing a 404 error. What could be causing this?

Comment: What exactly does the 401 error say? Chances are you need to talk to your hosting provider about this.

Comment: Sorry, I meant 404!